# How to Update SQLite database with new database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-room

I am new to

- SQLite
- Room Persistence Library

I am making mobile network bundles and offers app to show that I create database with Room Insert Annotation:

```
Insert
    void insertBundle(BundleOfferModel bundleOfferModel);
```

Then, the database is created in the app databases directory. I then copy that to my PC and add some new data into it, and copy the new modified database file to assets folder of apk. When I run my app again app shows old data but I want to see updated database file data. How can I accomplish this?

Database

```
@Database(entities = {BundleOfferModel.class}, version = 1,  exportSchema = false)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "bundles_offers.db";

    private static AppDatabase INSTANCE;

    public static AppDatabase getAppDatabase(Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, DATABASE_NAME )
                    .openHelperFactory(new AssetSQLiteOpenHelperFactory())
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public static void destroyInstance() {
        INSTANCE = null;
    }

    public abstract BundleOfferDao bundleDao();

}
```

Dao

```
@Dao
public interface BundleOfferDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insertBundle(BundleOfferModel bundleOfferModel);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM bundles_offers")
    List<BundleOfferModel> getAllBundlesOffers();

}
```